# Laravel make array of arrays

Tags: arrays, laravel

How get an array of many array ? foreach line 0-1-2-3(4-5 same object actually), actually objects.

How make it for get:

```
[ 1[] 2[] 3[4[]5[]] ]
```

Php code (laravel):

```
$array = array();
foreach($users as $u)
{
$x = User::where('xxx', 'xxx')->toArray();
array_push($array, $x);
}
return $array;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are trying to do and why you want to do it. It would help to answer the question.

Comment: Add an example with meaningful data (not just 1,2,3) so you can get proper help and even a recomendation to do what you want to do in a better way.

Comment: I've 2 for each, one on each User, and into another on each User keeped in array. 
I have to do like this. This must be into 2 for. And I want stack my user by same value. I can not use "groupby" because I've to use a foreach in foreach. So, return 1 array with for item, one another array who user have same value